# Replacing Value (URL) in Properties file in Unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to replace value of the property file in unix using Sed command. Here is the code:

Properties file:

```
Test.abc.homeURL:https://www.abdfghjc.net/instant-cash-offer/?from=1&LNX=TIMATCMOB&oCode=CMB
```

Shell:

> MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY="Test.abc.homeURL" 
>   MOBILE_REPLACE_URL="http://ww.xyz.com/default.html"
>
> sed -i
>   "s/^$MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY:.*/$MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY:$MOBILE_REPLACE_URL/"
>   propertiesFile

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 72: unknown option to `s'
```

Looks like some regular expression error, couldn't figure it out. please help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a different character than slash (/) to separate the sed parameters, because you have slashes in one of the variables ($MOBILE_REPLACE_URL).

Just use another character like #.  You also couldn't use colon because you have colon in your variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood , your requirement is to replace the key MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY with MOBILE_REPLACE_URL key's value.

Below is what I tried

sed  -e 's/^MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY=.*/MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY=\"http://ww.xyz.com/default.html\"/' newfile

newfile is the filename

Comment: sed  -e 's/^MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY=.*/MOBILE_HOME_PAGE_KEY=\"http\:\/\/ww\.xyz\.com\/default\.html\"/' newfile

Comment: When I posted some how backslash was not taken..so above the actual regex